# MAMP Installed: Conflict with standalone MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mamp

I've just installed MAMP. Now I'm worried because I already have a working standalone MySQL server. Should I abandon it? How do I transfer databases that use it to the MAMP environment?

Additionally I interface to it via Python, not PHP. Is this a problem with the MAMP MySQL?

(I've installed the MAMP because I want to install WordPress.)

I thought I posted this before, but I can't find it--forgive me if this is a differently phrased repeat.

thanks for any help, --thelma